# Can a class name instead of a namespace be pre-pended to :: for scope resolution?

Tags: c++, scope

So as I understand it, when I see double colons(abc::xyz) used the thing on the left is a namespace and the thing on the right can be a function or variable of some sort that is defined in that namespace.     ex. namespace::bar, namespace::foo()

Now, can the thing on the left be a class?     ex. class::bar, class::foo()

If so, does anyone have any info on this. I can find lots of info of scope resolution pertaining to namespaces but not when it comes to classes.

In my situation I am going through a rather large project of code that is from another individual. 
The code usage that I am trying to understand is that I have the following line of code...

```
multi_img::ptr input = imginput::ImgInput(config.input).execute();
```

On the right the imginput::ImgInput() can be found because there is a namespace imginput that I can find. But on the left, the multi_img::ptr, there is no multi_img namespace in the project. There is a multi_img class that contains the following line...

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<multi_img> ptr;
```

I believe this is what multi_img::ptr means but can not find any documentation to back up my assumption.

Comment: yes http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05cplr175.htm

Comment: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator) has a short example of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Now, can the thing on the left be a class?**

Yes it can, and to justify consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
  public:
    void fun() const { std::cout << "foo:fun()" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f.foo::fun();
    return 0;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96ac958c44d5462e)

- Every class member lies in the scope of its class.

Edit after [@Cheersandhth.-Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) constructive comment:

- Thus, you can access a member through an object with either the classical way (e.g., `f.fun()`) in which case you'll have a virtual call or you call it like in the example (i.e., `f.foo::fun()`) in which case you explicitly disambiguate the scope of member function at compile time.

Comment: re " what is really happening implicitly is f.foo::fun()", well no. `f.fun()` is not equivalent to `f.foo::fun()` in general. consider when `f` is of type `foo&`, and `fun` is virtual in `foo`, then `f.foo()` performs a virtual call while `f.foo::fun()` resolves the function at compile time.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks, as always accurate and constructive :) I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have a class name on the left of `::`. It is used to denote a member of that class. The `multi_img` class has a member called `ptr`. As you have shown, that member is a typedef. That is, the type `multi_img::ptr` is a synonym of `boost::shared_ptr<multi_img>`.

Note that `::` is used to access static members and nested types, since these only require the name of the class and not a particular object that of that class type. We use `.` and `->` to access non-static data members of a particular object.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimed it is difficult to know whether the nested name specifier denotes a namespace or a class because the syntax is the same. Moreother the same name can denote either a namespace or a class depending on the declaration region where the name is used. For example

```
namespace A
{
   struct A
   {
      static int a;
      static int b;
      static int c;
   };

   int A::a = 5;
}

int A::A::b = 10;
int A::A::c = a;
```

The most appropriate documentation is the C++ Standard. You may download a working draft of the Standard from the [ISO-IEC site](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/)

As for the typedef that defines a type

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<multi_img> ptr;
```

then it seems that it is defined in the class definition of multi_img. So if the name is used outside the class scope it shall be qualified

```
multi_img::ptr input = imginput::ImgInput(config.input).execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually the *classname*`::`*member* notation is used to

- Access static members.
  E.g. `Blah::uuid`.
- Prevent virtual call.
  E.g. in `Blah::foo`, a call like `Base::foo()`.
- Disambiguate.
  E.g. with two bases `A` and `B`, both of which provides a `foo`, a call like `B::foo()`.

Some older libraries use classes instead of namespaces. I vaguely recall an XML library and a GUI library. Not sure which.

Personally I do the class-as-faux-namespace for enumeration types, e.g.

```
struct Weekdays
    : Non_instantiable
{
    enum Enum { wednesday, friday, saturday };
};
```

used like

```
auto foo() -> Weekdays::Enum { return Weekdays::friday; }
```

even after C++11 started supported `enum class`.